# Using two divs with overlfow: hidden then overflow-y: scroll not working as expected

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

I am trying to use the trick of two nested  elements to make content scroll without the scrollbar being visible.

To illustrate what I mean:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
   //content here
  </div>
</div>
```

The content is higher than the outer div, so I want it to scroll. However I don't want a visible scrollbar. So I set the following CSS:

```
.outer {
overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
overflow-y: scroll;
width: 110%;
}
```

However this is behaving quite oddly. It works to an extent - the content scrolls slightly. However it doesn't scroll as far as it needs to to be visible, and the inner div seems to ignore the padding on the outer div.

This is my full CSS. The relevant bits are .section and .innerSection

```
/* Eric Meyer's Reset CSS v2.0 - http://cssreset.com */
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline;margin:0;padding:0}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block}body{line-height:1}ol,ul{list-style:none}blockquote,q{quotes:none}blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{content:none}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}

html, body {
    background-color: #330033;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;    
    color: #FFFFCC;
    font-family: 'Andika', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
}

a:link{text-decoration: none; color: #FFFFCC;}
a:visited{text-decoration: none; color: #FFFFCC;}
a:hover{text-decoration: none; color: white; font-weight: bold;}

form {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  text-align: left;
}

h1 {       
    font-size: 72px;

}

h2 {
    font-weight: 600;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 64px;
}

.imgLink {
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 1%;
    max-width: 50%;
}

.innerSection {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 110%;
}

.section {
    background-color: rgba(51,51,51,0.5);
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1%;
    max-height: 42%; /*simplifies responsive height lower down*/
    min-height: 42%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 1%;    
    vertical-align: top; /*otherwise sections move down when content added*/
    width: 28%;
}

#desktopTitle {
    background-color: #330033;
}

#tabletTitle {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1020px), screen and (max-height: 925px) {
    .section {
        display: block;
        max-height: fit-content;
        min-height: 25%;
        width: 94%;
    }

    #contact {
        margin-top: 5%;
    }

    #desktopTitle {
        display: none;
    }

    #resources {
        display: none;
    }

    #tabletTitle {
        display: block;
    }

    #twitter {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #tabletTitle {
        font-size: 48px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Need the inner div height 100%??

Comment: I find having it or removing it makes no difference - it seems to ignore that attribute entirely (I tried setting it to 50% to see what happened - made no difference) But in theory it should make it fill the outer div?

Answer (score 1):

Try this (modifications are commented):

```
.innerSection {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto; /*instead of scroll*/
    width: 110%;
    padding: 20px; /*add padding here*/
}

.section {
    background-color: rgba(51,51,51,0.5);
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1%;
    height: 100%; /*It does not seem to work without specifying a height.*/
    max-height: 42%;
    min-height: 42%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 1%;    
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 28%;
}
```

Comment: That works . . . I had played around with auto+padding, but I guess the height: 100% was what was missing. Although setting height: 100% and then max-height: 42% is a little bonkers! Thank you so much for your help :-)

Comment: You are welcome. :) I did not find any explanation why height has any effect while max-height overriding it. It has to do something with how overflow: hidden works.